# Does recvfrom() modify src_addr on error?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp, posix

I'm currently writing a small UDP socket library for personal use, but I've been unable to find any documentation on this.

The function I'm referring to is `ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`, from the POSIX `<sys/socket.h>` header.

I want to reuse the `src_addr` struct I'm passing to recvfrom for use with `sendto` (same header) regardless of whether `recvfrom` succeeds or fails. On success, it will contain the address of the peer sending it data (there's only one in my use case), which is the intended behavior; however, it generates the error `EAGAIN` when a non-blocking read fails, and the state of `src_addr` is then unclear. If `src_addr` isn't modified, it will still contain the target address and can be reused, but if it is then I'll have to use a temp variable.

Comment: "the state of `src_addr` is undefined" - where did you see this?

Comment: @immibis: I didn't; that's why I said it was undefined - as far as I can tell, it isn't documented anywhere. It's not the typical usage of "undefined" in a programming context (implicit instead of explicit), but the meaning is the same. All the same, I've updated the question.

Comment: You are overthinking it. Just use the temp variable. Call it "robustness", "portabiltity" or "forward compatibility" and move on.

Comment: POSIX says that the source address is written if addresses are specified by the protocol and its value is unspecified otherwise. Insofar, it is not strictly forbidden to overwrite the source address (say, with zeroes), but it's extra work and it wouldn't be particularly useful, so I doubt any implementation does it. Now of course you could also interprete the wording insofar as "UDP does (generally) provide addresses of messages", so the address field _is written_.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been dealing with this very same issue.
To add to your confusion, I have observed two different results :

- On WinCE 5.0, `recvfrom()` seemed to put zeroes into the `from` parameter when no bytes could be received
- Under On-Time RTOS (which claims compatibility with Win* API), the `from` parameter is left intact upon failed `recvfrom()`

I like RTOS' implementation better, because my application took the lazy approach of putting a pointer to the socket's known remote IP address. This same address was later used in `sendto()` calls just like @Techwolf did. It took me a while to figure out why the same code wouldn't work under WinCE.

Instead, I followed the advice of @Dummy00001 to choose for robustness.
By using a temp variable, the application can work on both of my platforms.

Incidentally, my application does "auto-detection" of the remote host in certain cases. The temp variable has a purpose to serve in this case. I'm copying it back into the permanent member associated with this socket - but only when `recvfrom()` has returned a positive number of bytes !